What is the equivalent of ((ClaimsIdentity)Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity) in .Net6
I have a console app in Net Framework 4.6.1 that implements
((ClaimsIdentity)Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity).AddClaim(new Claim(...))

I tried to migrate my app to .Net 6 but i got a NullReferenceException with this instruction.
I need the equivalent of this line of code in .Net6 so pretty simple please.
thank you

I guess it is quite important to also include the full exception stacktrace, to see which method is throwing the exception. Is it the Claim constructor ? Or the AddClaim method ?

Thread.CurrentPrincipal is null

this is probably the issue you are running into.
